# how to make a Sprite

Tags: sprite, css-sprites

ive used an online srpite service  http://spritegen.website-performance.org/  but i want to know how to make them by myself.

How can i save an image that it should be so small but when used on my web site it comes out normal size?

Answer (score 0):

Sprites aren't about making the image itself small, it's about decreasing filesize by packing several images into one.

Take a look at [Yahoo's icon sprite](http://l1.yimg.com/a/i/ww/met/pa_icons_18/20101213/spr_apps_us.png). Notice that they have all their section icons stacked vertically in one large image. They then use CSS to position the background to only show a small *window* of the sprite image, thus giving you just the icon.

In the end, it's up to you how you arrange your sprite. Check out the bottom of [Amazon's sprite](http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/gno/images/orangeBlue/navPackedSprites-US-22._V183711641_.png).

Either way, hopefully that helps gives you a better idea of the concept of sprites.

Comment: Welcome to 1990s game development.

Comment: Thank you! so where do i find out about decreasing the file size. When i click in photoshop save for web I get all these options. any good articles to explain what i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

From [the very site you link](http://spritegen.website-performance.org/section/what-are-css-sprites):

> CSS sprites are a way to reduce the
>   number of HTTP requests made for image
>   resources referenced by your site.
>   Images are combined into one larger
>   image at defined X and Y coorindates.
>   Having assigned this generated image
>   to relevant page elements the
>   background-position CSS property can
>   then be used to shift the visible area
>   to the required component image.

So there is nothing magical involved: you simply need to pack all your pictures into a single giant image with your favourite graphics tool and insert them as CSS background. Just look at this CSS sprite by Google:

[image: Google CSS Sprite]